# unexpected identifier while importing json document into mongodb with mongoimport command

Tags: json, mongodb, command-prompt

I am trying to import a json document into mongodb but it shows me unexpected identifier. my json document looks something like following

```
 [   
 {
"Cancer Sites":"Female Breast",
"State":"Alabama",
"Year":2000,
"Sex":"Female",
"Count":550
  },
   {
"Cancer Sites":"Female Breast",
"State":"Alabama",
"Year":2000,
"Sex":"Female",
"Count":2340
 },
 {
"Cancer Sites":"Female Breast",
"State":"Alabama",
"Year":2000,
"Sex":"Female",
"Count":45
  } 
   ]
```

I tried with following query from my mongo shell but it doesn't work

```
mongoimport -d treatment -c stats --file news.json
```

I am executing it from mongo shell on windows command prompt. my mongo shell is in C:\mongodb\bin path and my file is also in same path. can anyone tell where I am wrong

Comment: Execute it from the command prompt and not the client.

Comment: when I execute it directly from command prompt is show's me the following error : 'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable data or batch file.

Comment: Have you added `c:\mongodb\bin` to the PATH variable? or else traverse to that directory in the prompt and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

since it is a list of array we should use

```
mongoimport -d treatment -c stats --jsonArray news.json
```